# Method to choose overall winner across multiple categories

Tags: algorithms, optimization

I would like to create an algorithm that chooses an overall contest winner from an arbitrary number of participants where for each participant I have performance metrics across an arbitrary number of contests. The performance metric ranges from 0 to 1 for each category, the higher the better. The below table shows an example of the data I would like to choose a single winning participant from.

| participant_id | contest_1 | contest_2 | ... | contest_m |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| participant_1 | 0.8 | 0.33 | ... | 0.53 |
| participant_2 | 0.64 | 0.75 | ... | 0.78 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| participant_n | 0.50 | 0.66 | ... | .61 |

This seems like a fairly simple and common problem and I am wondering if there are any academic papers that have been published with optimized solutions?

Solutions I have used previously are to:

1. Choose the participant with the most overall category wins. This is not optimal because the winner could be strong in a few contests but relatively very weak in others.
2. Use a Mario Kart like ranking system, assigning points for each contest based on performance ranking. The issue I have with this is that the number of points assigned to each participant based on its ranking in a contest is seemingly arbitrary and needs to be adjusted based on the number of participants.

Comment: If the order of the m-contests matter then the elo system is the most used. FIFA and FIAB are using such a system. Chess and Tennis have similar variations.

Comment: You have not stated the criterion for selecting the winning participant, only the data that could manipulated in an unstated way to compute an overall performance value for each participant.